# Shuffle not working in Java

Tags: java, arrays, collections, shuffle

I'm trying to do a code for a project. The project consists of adding, removing, shuffling and reordering(moving) Strings.
I am currently stuck on shuffle. I am using `import java.util.Collections` and I'm stuck. What I mean is by using the code bellow I am getting an exception:

```
private static void ShuffleTrack(int[] array) {
    Collections.swap(mp3Player, 0, 1);  
    System.out.println(""+mp3Player);
}
```

Here is the exception I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
    at java.util.Collections.swap(Collections.java:497)
    at mp3Player.ShuffleTrack(mp3Player.java:78)
    at mp3Player.main(mp3Player.java:40)
```

I am not getting any errors in the actual program, just the console.

Here is the code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

public class mp3Player {
public static Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);

public static ArrayList<Track> mp3Player = new ArrayList<Track>();

public static void main(String[] args ){
    //declare variables
    int menu = 0;

do{ 
    System.out.println("***WELCOME***");
    System.out.println(" This is my MP3 Album ");
    System.out.println("Please Choose one of the following options:");
    System.out.println("1.Add a Track");
    System.out.println("2.Search for a Track");
    System.out.println("3.Delete an exisiting Track");
    System.out.println("4.Shuffle Tracks");
    System.out.println("5.Reorder Tracks");

    menu = in.nextInt(); //Record user choice

    switch(menu){
    case 1:
        InsertTrack();
        break;

    //case 2:
        //SearchTrack();
    //  break;

    //case 3: 
        //DeleteTrack();
        //break;

    case 4: 
        ShuffleTrack(null);
        //break;

    case 5:
        //ReorderTrack();
        //break;


    }//end of switch

} while(menu !=0); //End of loop

} // End of static void

private static void InsertTrack(){

    Track newtrack = new Track();

    System.out.println("Track Number: ");
    int Tracknumber = in.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Artist Name: ");
    String TrackArtist = in.next();

    System.out.println("Track Name: ");
    String TrackName = in.next();

    System.out.println("Track Duration: ");
    String TrackDuration = in.next();

    System.out.println("Your Track has been added.");

    newtrack.setTrack(Tracknumber, TrackArtist, TrackName, TrackDuration);

}//End of InsertTrack

private static void ShuffleTrack(int[] array){

    Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(mp3Player));

    }//End Of ShuffleTrack  


    //Set Attributes
    private String InsertTrack ="";
    private String SearchTrack ="";
    private String DeleteTrack = "";
    private String ShuffleTrack = "";
    private String ReorderTrack = "";

    // Setting Methods
    public void setMp3(String InsertTrack, String SearchTrack, String DeleteTrack, String ShuffleTrack, String ReorderTrack){


        this.InsertTrack = InsertTrack;
        this.SearchTrack = SearchTrack;
        this.DeleteTrack = DeleteTrack;
        this.ShuffleTrack = ShuffleTrack;
        this.ReorderTrack = ReorderTrack;

    }// End of Method

    public String getInsertTrack(){
        return InsertTrack;
    }
    public String getSearchTrack(){
        return SearchTrack;
    }
    public String getDeleteTrack(){
        return DeleteTrack;
    }
    public String getShuffleTrack(){
        return ShuffleTrack;
    }
    public String ReorderTrack(){
        return ReorderTrack;
    }
```

}//End of Class

Comment: I removed your "new question". If you have another question, then please create one. You shouldn't ask multiple questions in a single post.

Comment: The stack trace says that `mp3Player`, which apparently is an `ArrayList`, is empty when you attempt to swap (nonexistent) elements at indices `0` and `1`.  We have no way to tell you why it's empty, but it should be obvious that you cannot swap elements that do not exist.

Comment: Alright I sort of understand it, for some reason it basically show that i did not add anything ;/ i have a Add Track option as well to which i add tracks and i've added a few and still shows the same error ;/.   **Sorry for adding the second question**

Comment: @Vickz, at this point, the list is clearly empty. You'll need to post more if you want help solving the bug.

Comment: Yes, please add the code where you add tracks to the `mp3Player` list.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Edited post with added code

Comment: Your `InsertTrack` just creates a track, but doesn't add it to the list.

Comment: Alright, I see, how do I make it to add it to the list now ?

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply use `Collections.shuffle()`?

It would look something like this:

```
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(array));
```

Comment: Kick's me back to the menu.

Comment: That shuffles a list that you don't have a reference to... It didn't make sense...

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it working,
Missed a bit of code which made it not save in the actual array fixed it by this adding this at the end of CreateTrack

```
mp3Player.add(newtrack);
```